# Class must implement the public interface method

Tags: apex

I'm getting the below error based on the code I've written. How do I fix it?

**Error**

> customerPurchaseOrder: Class must implement the public interface method: Double Discount() from PurchaseOrder

**Apex**

```
public interface PurchaseOrder {
    Double Discount();

}
public class customerPurchaseOrder implements PurchaseOrder{

    public Double getDiscount(){

        return .05;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see [Ask] if you get an error message why would you not post it. We do not get paid to diagnose. You will find that when you make people guess at the information you readily have available you will get less help.

Answer (score 3):

If you are implementing an interface, then the implementation class should have same method body which has been defined at interface.

Here customerPurchaseOrder class didn't have method body of Discount(), that's why you are facing compilation error.

For more information, refer [Extended Class Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_example.htm) and [Understanding Interfaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_interfaces.htm)

```
public interface PurchaseOrder {
    Double Discount();

}

public class customerPurchaseOrder implements PurchaseOrder{

    public Double Discount(){

        return .05;
    }
}
```